# Is `dmsetup remove` safe with respect to contained data?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid-1, mdadm

I have a "lost" SW RAID array as described in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/311024/raid1-array-lost-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-11-10-to-13-04. I have now identified a way to mount one of the original (mirrored) RAID members so as to extract the data from it.
Now I would like to get the current RAID setup out of the way (there is currently a set-up on the drives that was wrongly auto-detected in a previous attempt to recover the array). This wrongly auto-detected RAID set-up was created using `mdadm --assemble --scan` and now several RAID (or LVM - I don't know) devices appear:

```
/dev/dm-0
/dev/dm-1
/dev/dm-2
```

Only `/dev/dm-1` appears to be active.
Is is safe to use `dmsetup remove` to remove these set-ups? That is, will this only remove the meta data about the RAID setups and safely leave the partitions on the member devices unaltered?